How is positional encoding done in wav2vec 2.0?
The "wav2vec 2.0: A Framework for Self-Supervised Learning of Speech Representations" quickly describes the positional embedding method with:

Instead of fixed positional
embeddings which encode absolute positional information, we use a convolutional layer similar
to [37 , 4 , 57 ] which acts as relative positional embedding.


[4] A. Baevski, M. Auli, and A. Mohamed. Effectiveness of self-supervised pre-training for speech
recognition. arXiv, abs/1911.03912, 2019.


[37] A. Mohamed, D. Okhonko, and L. Zettlemoyer. Transformers with convolutional context for ASR. arXiv, abs/1904.11660, 2019.


[57] F. Wu, A. Fan, A. Baevski, Y. N. Dauphin, and M. Auli. Pay less attention with lightweight and dynamic convolutions. In Proc. of ICLR, 2019.

[4] talks about convolutional positional encoding in the context of BERT, stating:

we replace the fixed positional embeddings
in the BERT model with a single group convolutional layer
that is applied directly on the embeddings before any of the
transformer blocks. The convolutional layer has a kernel size
of 128 and group size of 16 to reduce the number of added
parameters.

[37] says:

We propose replacing sinusoidal positional embedding with contextually
augmented inputs learned by 2-D convolutional layers over
input speech features in the encoder, and by 1-D convolutional
layers over previously generated outputs in the decoder

While [57], without mentioning convolutions, states:

We add sinusoidal position embeddings to encode the absolute position of each word in the sequence.

